# How to find GMT date/time by country name?

Tags: php, datetime, localization

How can I find country name -> GMT date/time to that I can do like following:

Example:

```
$datetime = new GMT_search('America');  //output: 2010-01-01 00:00:00    
$datetime = new GMT_search('India');  //output: 2010-01-01 ??:??:??    
$datetime = new GMT_search('China');  //output: 2010-01-01 ??:??:??
```

I tried `gmdate()`, `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/....');`, and `ini_set('date.timezone','China');` but it’s not exactly helping me to find easily country name to GMT date/time.

Can anyone please kindly show me a PHP example, which really works?

Thank you

Comment: Need clarification, is finding supported timezones the problem?

Comment: What about countries with multiple time zones?

Comment: And China, too. When did "China" become a country?

Comment: @NullUserException: There, fixed that. For a moment I thought you must be from Canada. :P

Comment: What exactly dou you mean with "GMT date/time"? GMT (or, more correctly, UTC) is specifically *not* country-dependant.

Comment: @GZipp It is generally accepted that China became a country 2,231 years ago when the [Qin dinasty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_Dynasty) unified the country. By the way that's where the name "China" comes from - "Qin". Chinese civilization has been around for over 5,000 years.

Comment: I want a date/time search by COUNTRY NAME (not city). example: $country = array('America' =>'New_York', 'Asia'=>'India'); ?? how!!!

Comment: @NullUserException - "Chinese civilization has been around for over 5,000 years." No shit?

Comment: @Stackfan: Countries may have several [time zones](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cd/Timezones2010.png): The USA have six time zones and Russia even eight.

Comment: OK - Make me stupid, I understand country like (usa/russia have more, but that is not my problem), All i am trying just to do select by COUNTRY NAME. example url click country get details example this i am trying to make!: wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/time-zone/all.htm

Comment: @Gumbo, Pekka Usually countries have a single "official" time zone. For example, for Russia it's Moscow time (GMT -4).

Comment: Yes!! Capital/Down town i am talking. (COUNTRY NAME + CAPITAL) === COUNTRY NAME === TimeZone search!????

Comment: @Stackfan You'll have to elaborate on that. America is equivalent to Asia (they are continents, **not** countries). But India is a country, and New York is at most a state.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can search the timezones by country with [`DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.listidentifiers.php).

Example, to get the timezones in Portugal:

```
print_r(DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::PER_COUNTRY, "PT"));
```

gives:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Atlantic/Azores
    [1] => Atlantic/Madeira
    [2] => Europe/Lisbon
)
```

You can then do:

```
$d = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("Atlantic/Azores"));
echo $d->format(DateTime::W3C); //2010-08-14T15:22:22+00:00
```

As has been repeated over and over again in this thread, you can't get one single time zone per country. Countries have several timezones, and you'll notice that even [this page](http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/time-zone/all.htm) doesn't even select one arbitrarily for some countries like the U.S.A.

Comment: Thanks, i was trying to find how Country Name/Land code to reach City or Timezone. ex: print_r(DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::PER_COUNTRY, "PT"));

Comment: The perfect thing/beauty of your code example is here: 1. I will put land code now to search whatever 2. i will check the array length and pick any one 3. i have my result. Thanks again..

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/) has a "[Date](http://pear.php.net/package/Date/redirected)" package available that has a nice example that seems to do what you are asking for.

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.datetime.date.examples.php (scroll down to "Converting timezones")

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) you'll find the complete list of timezones supported by PHP, which are meant to be used with e.g. `date_default_timezone_set()`. Support for countries with multiple timezones is also convenient to look up. Take the [example of the American region](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php).

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
echo date('D,F j, Y, h:i:s A');
?>
```

The list is a complete timezones supported by PHP, which are meant to be used with e.g. date_default_timezone_set().

Comment: I have country only, NO CITY database. How can you make Country To::GMT_DateTime?

Comment: Should i have to make, country with default city? I dont want to specific city date/time? But again i have problem with Asia or Europe?. ex: $country = array('America'=>'New_York', 'India'=>'Mumbai', 'China' =>'Sangai');

Comment: There is the possibility that a country will have more than one timezone. So trying to convert a country name would produce inaccurate results.

Comment: You mean you only have the country information but not the city? Or are you looking for [this](http://pecl.php.net/get/timezonedb)? If you only have country information you may store all capitals maybe? And like cdburgess said, what about countries with multiple timezones?

Comment: How can i put here COUNTRY NAME? array('America'=>'New_York', 'Asia'=>'India', 'Asia'=>'China');???? wrong!!   ex: date_default_timezone_set(array.key . '/' . array.value); // wrong again

Comment: OK - I understand country like (usa/russia have more, but that is not my problem), I am trying just to do select by COUNTRY NAME. EX: wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/time-zone/all.htm

Comment: No, I meant, if you (on your part out of your project constraints) don't have a city you wanna lookup the timezone of, then you store them as per the city that defines the timezone. Like for India you have `Asia/Calcutta`.

Comment: You can't have it by country using that. I'm suggesting storing the relevant cities for the country.

Comment: http://countrycode.org/   almost this table in my database, one new field will be coming call TimeZone.

My database table fields: ID, Country, CountryCode, TimeZone, Telephone code;;;; Row-1: 1, United States, US, America/New_York, 1;;;; Row2: 2, India, IN, Asia/Mumbai, 91;;;; So a user is controled by COUNTRY CODE OR COUNTRY NAME, automatically that user timezone is 1 timezone, even if you are in calcuta/other city (not my issue).  ex: date_default_timezone_set('India'); 

Thats why, Can you do this by COUNTRY NAME with one default city on it? And is this a GMT time getting returned?

Comment: Why do you need this if I may ask? You can [get visitors local time using PHP and JavaScript](http://www.webmasterworld.com/php/3398104.htm) if you would like that or you can get someone to select their timezone from a drop-down like most forums do. But I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Call center for A to B and B to C with other D/E/F Time Zone programmers, based on Country (not city).

Comment: Don't quite get you. Do the options I suggest in the comment above work for you? I'm sorry to say, there aren't any timezones by country. Because not all countries have *a* (singular) timezone just like you suggested. They can have multiple.

Comment: Or does [determining timezone by IP](http://derickrethans.nl/detecting-timezone-by-ip.html) work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it quite like that, since a lot of countries have multiple timezones. You could store the timezone by the name of a city instead, but I'd use an integer with the timezone offset in seconds.

You can get a list of timezones by continent/city from this function:
[www.php.net/manual/en/function.timezone-identifiers-list.php][1]

You can get the respective offset from this function:
[www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.getoffset.php][2]

When you have a valid offset, you can use gmdate() instead of date() to get a date in your format without the timezone/dst adjustment. Just pass the time() + the ajustment you have stored:
[www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php][3]

Comment: I am trying this where you select only COUNTRY NAME. EX: http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/time-zone/all.htm

Comment: That i dont want. Its about COUNTRY NAME.

Comment: @Stackfan: Yes, I chose the "United States of America" link which brought me to .../time-zone/usa and the mentioned page content. So, you gave an example of what you _don't_ want? You also wrote `Yes!! Capital/Down town i am talking. (COUNTRY NAME + CAPITAL) === COUNTRY NAME === ` , which one is it? `country name` or `country name+capital` ?