# How to get time zone in php by passing country code or country name

Tags: php

I have country code and country name using some api, is there any way to get time zone of given country code and country name in php. I have data like this,

```
address:Object
city:"-"
continent:"Asia"
continent_code:"AS"
country:"India"
country_code:"IN"
```

I am getting this data, i want to get time zone of given address, Is there any way to do in php.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find GMT date/time by country name?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3483519/3361444)

Comment: You could just create yourself a lookup table; but what do you do in cases like Australia or the USA that span multiple timezones? Better to use the proper identifiers

Answer (score 20):

If you do not want to install the PECL library.

You can use DateTimeZone:

`$timezone = \DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(\DateTimeZone::PER_COUNTRY, $countryCode);`

Comment: I am getting likeArray ( [0] => America/Adak [1] => America/Anchorage [2] => America/Boise [3] => America/Chicago [4] => America/Denver [5] => America/Detroit [6] => America/Indiana/Indianapolis [7] => America/Indiana/Knox [8] => America/Indiana/Marengo [9] => America/Indiana/Petersburg [10] => America/Indiana/Tell_City [11] => America/Indiana/Vevay [12] => America/Indiana/Vincennes [13] => America/Indiana/Winamac [14] => America/Juneau [15] => America/Kentucky/Louisville [16] => America/Kentucky/Monticello [17] => .... when using country code of US using your solution

Comment: @SayedMohdAli Use the country iso2

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a function for it using GeoIP.

The `geoip_time_zone_by_country_and_region()` function will return the time zone corresponding to a country and region code combo.

```
$timezone = geoip_time_zone_by_country_and_region('CA', 'QC');
if ($timezone) {
    echo 'Time zone for CA/QC is: ' . $timezone;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-time-zone-by-country-and-region.php

You will need to download and include the GeoIP library
http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoIPCountryCSV.zip

Comment: I tried your code but i am getting error Call to undefined function geoip_time_zone_by_country_and_region() in

Comment: you need to include the GeoIP in you site. `http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/` I have updated my answer to include link

Comment: this isn't supported by php8

Answer (score 0):

If you only have Country Name information, you might not be able to reverse look up all time zones.

For example, United States has 5 different time zones. It is a one to many relationship.