# How do I get the UTC Offset in PHP

Tags: php

I have a list of timezones name in by database:

- America/Anchorage
- America/Yakutat
- America/Sitka
- America/Nome
- America/Juneau
- Canada/Yukon
- ...

I need to get the **UTC Offset** in **PHP**. For example for **America/Anchorage** I need to have `UTC-9` and so on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942933/how-to-get-time-zone-in-php-by-passing-country-code-or-country-name

Comment: Please ask that in the form of a question. For example, "how do I get the UTC Offset in PHP?"

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
  $dateTimeZoneJapan = new DateTimeZone("America/Adak");
  $timeOffset = $dateTimeZoneJapan->getOffset( new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("UTC"))  );
if ($timeOffset < 0){ //if time offset is negative
  echo "-".gmdate("H", -$timeOffset);
}else{
  echo gmdate("H", $timeOffset); //H will give number of hours. 
}
```

this will give you time zone offset in seconds on success or FALSE on failure.

Comment: Your example do not work correctly for example for "America/Adak" it gives 14, but it must be -10